# PostgreSQL jsonb array query

Tags: json, postgresql, contains, jsonb

This current query only uses 2 keys that should be unequal to zero, but I want to create a query that allows me to say, the following 20 keys should all be unequal to zero without having to type it out like this manually. However, I can't seem to find the equivalent (Speed is important here, so preferably a solution that uses the same kind of expression).

This is my current query:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_schema.my_table
where updated_at > 'now'::timestamp - '1 day'::INTERVAL
AND jsonb_column @? '$ ? (@.key1 != 0 || @.key2!= 0 )'
```

This is how I want to extend it.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_schema.my_table
where updated_at > 'now'::timestamp - '1 day'::INTERVAL
AND jsonb_column @? '$ ? (@.key1 != 0 || @.key2 != 0 || @.key3 != 0 || @.key4 != 0 || @.key5 != 0)'
```

But now I want it to write it in a more concise way rather than manually having to add e.g. `|| @.key6 != 0` for each key.

Hope somebody could point me in the right direction! Thank you so much!

I have tried using an exists clause with jsonb_each, but this seems to be twice as slow. So I am trying to get a more concise and clear notation of the above.

EDIT after comment from Benji, but this performs twice as slow on a large table:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_schema.my_table
WHERE updated_at > 'now'::timestamp - '1 day'::INTERVAL and not EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM jsonb_each(jsonb_column) AS j(k, v)
  WHERE j.v::text = '0'
  AND j.k=ANY(ARRAY['key1', 'key2'])
)
```

This is my fastest solution so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_schema.my_table
WHERE updated_at > 'now'::timestamp - '1 day'::INTERVAL and    
AND (abs((jsonb_column->>'key1')::float) > 0
    or abs((jsonb_column->>'key2')::float) > 0)
```

Comment: Is your jsonb column indexed?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt at using `jsonb_each`, please?

Comment: If speed is important, the fastest way is to use a `UNION` of queries, each of which queries one key. That can use an index. Now you are asking for a concise solution. I doubt that there is a more concise one than the one you already have, but and such solution (as well as your current query) won't perform well on a large table.

Comment: I added the comment on the attempt at using jsonb_each. and how would I do this Laurenz? Could you maybe provide an example.

Comment: It is indexed by updated_at, so the jsonb column is not.

Comment: Try `where not jsonb_column @? '$.keyvalue() ? (@.value == 0)'`

Comment: Btw: `'now'::timestamp` can be written as `localtimestamp`

Comment: both are much slower unfortunately

Comment: Notice your `jsonb_each` solution does do something slightly different: it matches only when *all* of the keys in the array have a non-null value in the object, and it also matches on objects that don't have the keys at all.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner (less repetitive) solution would be

```
SELECT *
FROM my_schema.my_table
WHERE updated_at > 'now'::timestamp - '1 day'::INTERVAL
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM unnest(ARRAY['key1', 'key2', …]) key
    WHERE (jsonb_column ->> key)::float <> 0
  );
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM my_schema.my_table
WHERE updated_at > 'now'::timestamp - '1 day'::INTERVAL
  AND (
    SELECT bool_or((jsonb_column ->> key)::float <> 0)
    FROM unnest(ARRAY['key1', 'key2', …]) key
  );
```

I don't know if they're faster though. Neither will be able to use an index on the `jsonb_column`, however I guess that an index on `updated_at` is more important anyway.